# WSL: Value of v:event.regname for non-alpha-numeric registers

Tags: autocmd, register, wsl

I have a rather slow `autocmd TextYankPost` command that I'm trying to limit to the quoteplus (+) register. I've tried the following to get this to work:

`autocmd TextYankPost * if v:event.regname is '+' | ...slow stuff... | endif`

However it doesn't work. It looks like most registers that aren't alpha-numeric don't have a regname for this purpose. For example if I do the following:

`:autocmd TextYankPost * echomsg v:event.regname`

I don't get anything printed to the screen for the `+`, `*`, or even `"` registers. I've discovered this is only a problem on WSL. Running a vim with the exact same `vim --version` output on a true Linux box does print `+`, `*`, or even `"`.

How can I limit my TextYankPost to only the `+` register on WSL?

Note: I know I could use another register like `u`, but `+` is more intuitive as my command pertains to copying to the GUI.

Comment: What version of Vim are you using? I get the desired result in 9.0.1544 and 9.1.0.

Comment: vim 9.0 with patches: 1-749.  This does work on my Linux box which has the same version, and on Windows in gVim, but not in WSL. Kind of annoying as my slow command is only needed for WSL. I see the WSL version is "without GUI." I'm guessing that's the problem.

Comment: Nope. Reinstalled vim with gui support, and still the same problem. Also tried `-u NONE`. Maybe it's a problem specific to vim on WSL. The output of `vim --version` is identical.

Comment: Filed a bug: https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/14304